# MYSQL INNER JOIN with Empty columns

Tags: mysql, join, null, inner-join

I'm trying to use MYSQL's INNER JOIN using two optional clauses. But it doesn't seem to be returning all the data. Any tips on how I can improve this query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM ImportedContacts t1 
INNER JOIN users t2 
    ON (t1.Emails = t2.email OR 
        t1.Phones = t2.Phone) 
WHERE t1.Username = 'user' AND 
  NOT t2.email = '' 
ORDER BY t2.first_name 
  LIMIT 60
```

**EDITED**

I changed the title from "MYSQL INNER JOIN with OR Clause" to the current one to make it easier to find for people having the same problem. It turns out this issue actually had to do with the columns being JOINED having empty or null values.  The accepted answer explains the cause of the problem and provides a solution.

Comment: `But it doesn't seem to be returning all the data` Without actual data we cannot guess. Do you mean some NULL values in email/phone number?

Comment: no i mean its leaving out some rows.

Comment: Which rows? Are you aware we cannot see your actual data? Can you just post sample data that should be returned but your query omits them?

Comment: @user2993497 please give some sample data and expected output, as well as output you are getting. Without that, noone can figure out what is wrong!

Comment: Yes I am. I basically want to know if there is a better way to query this data as I don't have the permission to share the actual data.

Comment: understood. @MadhurBhaiya i will try gimme a sec

Comment: @user2993497 You could simply exchange real email/phone with `XYZ@mycompany.com/1234567` equivalents.

Comment: `I don't have the permission to share the actual data` We are never interested in the actual data, just that any `sample data` is `representative' of the actual  so that we can accurately understand your problem.

Comment: Okay so I just observed the data. the missing rows are exactly like the rows that are being returned. For instance the missing rows and the ones that are returned all have emails, phones, usernames and first_names in both tables.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda can you explain?

Comment: @user2993497 We don't need your **actual data** but sample scenario when your query fails. Simple as that.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda when I remove the second query in the or clause (`t1.Phones = t2.Phone`) it's successful. The `t1.Phones` column is empty. however, in both tables, the emails are exactly the same. With the use of my `OR` clause, I expected it to be returned.

Comment: `t1.Username = 'user'` is also true for these missing rows

Comment: @user2993497 please put some effort on preparing a sample data reproducing your case. just one case is enough. Words are not going to replace a sample data with expected behaviour

Comment: Is t1.Phones empty or `NULL`?

Comment: @Nick yes t1.Phones is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. According to this [article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-the-effects-of-nulls-on-inner-and-outer-joins/), `INNER JOIN` won't work with fields that have `NULL` or empty values. The Answer above didn't work since the CLAUSE that was meant to filter out the `NULL` columns ran after the `INNER JOIN` was evaluated with the `NULL` or empty columns. So considering this information I filtered out the `NULL` columns in the actual `INNER JOIN` statement as opposed to after.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   importedcontacts 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON ( users.email = importedcontacts.emails 
                     OR ( ( importedcontacts.phones = users.phone ) 
                          AND NOT importedcontacts.phones = '' 
                          AND NOT users.phone = '' ) ) 
WHERE  importedcontacts.username = 'user' 
ORDER  BY users.first_name
```

And it worked! thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have not null values  too

```
SELECT * 
FROM ImportedContacts t1 
INNER JOIN users t2 ON (t1.Emails = t2.email OR t1.Phones = t2.Phone) 
WHERE t1.Username = 'user' 
AND  ( NOT t2.email = '' OR   t2.email IS NOT NULL ) 
ORDER BY t2.first_name LIMIT 60
```

Comment: thanks alot for the input. I know this isn't it becasue even without the `NOT t2.email = ''` it doesnt work as expected.